# Java Strings dont work right anymore

Tags: java

Okay so I'm learning java and everything was working fine yesterday, and all of the sudden today all of the stuff i wrote (just some super basic stuff) no longer work, for example

```
package sectionOne;

public class AddingNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int x = 10;
        int y = 20;
        int result = x+y;
        System.out.println(result);

    }

}
```

gives me error:

> Error: Main method not found in class sectionOne.AddingNumbers, please define the main method as:
>      public static void main(String[] args)
>   or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Unless I change this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

to this:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) {
```

the program won't work. Also when I create a string like

```
String x = "test";
```

it won't work unless I do

```
java.lang.String x = "test";
```

What's going on?

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: Do you have String class in your current package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a class that has the same name as the java.lang.String class in your namespace so:
1->try to search in every import and, if you find some String class imported, remove it.
2->search in your package if there is a class named String and rename it

if you did this and it still doesn't work, then your compiler has some problems :/

Answer (score 7):

You've got your own class named `String` that is causing conflicts with the compiler -- rename it to *anything* else (that doesn't conflict with core class names that is).

Comment: Answered as a comm wiki since there has to be many dups of this question.

Comment: And, lesson for the future: consider any class name in java.lang to be off-limits for your classes. I'd throw in any class in the common jdk classes, too: java.util, java.io, etc. When in doubt, don't shadow a class that's defined in the jdk.

Comment: `to anything else`---let's hope that doesn't end up as `CharacterSequence` :)